# How to skip empty array Observer?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I use `combineLatest` operator:

```
   combineLatest(...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges)).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
   });
```

It gets the laste emitted changes in each stream: `f.filtersChanges` and return array of values: `[value1, value2]`.

My problem is that if there are not changes in return array of nulls: `[null, null]`.

How to replace it on just `null` or boolean?

I have tried filter:

```
combineLatest(...this.filtersList.filter((filter) => filter.filtersChanges.getValue()).map((f) => f.filtersChanges)).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            },
        );
```

But it never works, if remove `filter()` it worksю

This is working, but not skipping `[null, null]`:

```
combineLatest(this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges)).subscribe((data) => {
});
```

Comment: I think because by default it is null, it can not subscribe, but I need filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand the question. But if you wish to remove all the `null` elements in the array returned by the statment `...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges)`, then you could try to use the `filter()` function to the array retuned from the `map()` function. Try the following

```js
combineLatest(...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges).filter(f => f !== null)).subscribe(
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
combineLatest(...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges))
.pipe(skipWhile(result => result.every(val => val == null)))
.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

To skip any emission of result if some value in your subscription is null. Or you can use `result.some` if you no need any values `null` with other data.

And this variant if you need `false` result when data is null.

```
combineLatest(...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges))
.pipe(map(result => result.every(val => val == null) ? false : result))
.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: it skips all values if only one is null. So if [1, null] it does not go to subscribe

Comment: As I wrote, use result.every to not skip null values.
combineLatest(...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges))
.pipe(skipWhile(result => result.every(val => val == null)))
.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

Comment: It requires that all observers returns not emply, not null. It does not work

Comment: Are you properly use my code? I edited it now for your reason.

Comment: it emits again `[null, null]`

Comment: [null, null] goes to false, [null, "1"] goes to [null, "1']